# Replace NA with mean value for specific day and grid

Tags: r, na

I am using a large dataset and I am not used to using one this big (286,212 rows, 19 columns) and I am not sure how to go about my problem. the data is made up of values for each day of the year for 782 grid references and I have this for 15 years. It looks as follows

```
**Month  Day  Grid   x2004    x2005    x2006     x2007**
 1       1    A10    0.091   0.134     NA       0.066
 1       2    A10    0.12    0.10      0.23     0.054
 1       3    A10    0.55    NA        NA       0.08
 1       1    B10    NA      0.134     NA       0.17
 1       2    B10    0.14    0.151     NA       0.21
 1       3    B10    0.43    0.162     0.24      NA
```

However some of the days are missing and I want to insert the mean of that day for that specific grid using values from the other years. So if the Grid A10 for day 1 in 2006 is missing. I want to insert the mean for day 1 grid A10 from 2004, 2005, 2007, in this case 0.097.

I am trying the following code

```
ind <- which(is.na(data$x2005))
data$x2005[ind] <- sapply(ind, function(i) 
with(data, rowMeans(data[c(data$x2004[i], data$x2006[i], data$x2007[i], data$x2008[i], data$x2009[i],
data$x2010[i], data$x2011[i], data$x2012[i], 
data$x2013[i], data$x2014[i], data$x2015[i], 
data$x2016[i], data$x2017[i]),], na.rm=TRUE)))
```

and I plan to do that for all years but it is telling me

```
"Error in rowMeans(data[c(data$x2006[i], data$x2007[i], data$x2012[i]),  : 
  'x' must be numeric"
```

Although when I check class, it says that they are all numeric, so I am not sure why x is not numeric. I also don't know if even when i get the mean part sorted, if the code will work so that I am getting the mean specific to each grid and day.

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: There are dupes for this `library(zoo);library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(Day, Grid) %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("x"), na.aggregate)`

Comment: Sorry, I dont really know what you mean? and that isnt working.

Comment: Can u show the expected output

Comment: Where is 2002, 2003 in the example `I want to insert the mean for day 1 grid A10 from 2002, 2003, 2005, in this case 0.097.`

Comment: Please update it in your post by `edit`ing the post

Comment: Sorry, that was a little confusing editing the query now. 
The expected output would be as follows

`Month  Day  Grid   x2004    x2005    x2006     x2007
   1           1    A10    0.091     0.134     0.097       0.066
   1           2    A10    0.12      0.10        0.23         0.054
   1           3    A10    0.55      0.063      0.063       0.08
   1           1    B10    0.152    0.134      0.152       0.17
   1           2    B10    0.14      0.151      0.167       0.21
   1           3    B10    0.43      0.162      0.24         0.416`

Answer (score 0):

Can you adapt this to your code:

`for(i in 1:ncol(data)){
  data[is.na(data[,i]), i] <- mean(data[,i], na.rm = TRUE)
}`

Comment: No, that didn't work. think it found the overall mean and inserted it, rather than the mean for that specific day

Comment: I think that is finding the column mean and adding it in. I am not sure how to calculate the row mean to add in, any suggestions? rowMeans doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe change to [i,] and ncol to nrow